# Joomla - How to fix a broken link displayed in "Publications by date" section

Tags: joomla

I need to fix a broken link on this page [here](http://www.csvr.org.za/publications/publications-by-date?start=90), 3rd line (Living with the Legacy of Impunity: Lessons...)

and I did find that article in the article section.

My concern is now : How do I fix that broken link from "Publications by date" section. although I know that "Publications by date" section is some kind of automatic module that go fetch all articles newly written/published.

So How do I get into "Publications by date" section/module in order to fix that broken link?

Below is the image of that article I found in edit mode.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMLFG.png)

Comment: Thanks so much !